# What is the difference in using "Il est retard" and "Il est en retard"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, verbes

What is the difference in using "Il est retard" and "Il est en retard"?
If they are same, then how and why the two forms?
I am new to French.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT** (thanks to users @jlliagre, @ Luke Sawczak, @ yagmoth555 for their feedback.)

**(1)**
You might have been confused by the non negligible number of occurrences of

> **il est retard**

Google returns. User @jlliagre even found one in the "Grevisse de l'étudiant" 2017, missed by proofreaders...   :

[image]

**The expression is nevertheless invalid**. While the **en** *is unstressed and often no more nasalized* (*il est a r'tard*), it is still there.

**(2)** The idiom

> **il est en retard**

is correct and it conveys

> he is late (speaking of someone) *or* it is late (speaking of something)

*Être en retard* is a *set expression* which can be conveyed in English by 'to be late'. French only sometimes is conveyed word-by-word by a English structure. Conversely, English only sometimes is conveyed word-by-word by a French structure.

As another example, take **être en congés** (be on holidays). Yet another one, **être en phase** and so on.

I think *être* and *retard* (a noun) does not make sense. It is by **en** that the whole set expression conveys *be late* (late is an adjective here).

*Être* + noun only works for identity things, such as professions. "Il est médecin." Since retard means "delay", the construction would be ungrammatical. Even if *être retard* did work, it would apparently mean "He is a delay." (thanks @ Luke Sawczak).

**(3)**

> **il est retardé**

can mean, depending on the context,

> il est en retard dans son développement intellectuel.

> he/it is delayed.

**The usual sense is the latter one**. The interesting point is the comparison between **il est retardé** and **il est en retard**. (thanks to user @jlliagre for the clarification)

> The difference between "il est en retard" and "il est retardé" is that
> in the former case, the expected time is over, or will be necessarily
> over (it's too late to be on time) while in the latter case, the
> expected time hasn't yet arrived. The person or object delayed might
> even be able to catch up the delay.
>
> One shouldn't focus too much on the meaning "he is mentally deficient"
> because it is anecdotal here and the context should clearly sort out
> what is intended, not to mention it has no sense if "il" isn't a
> person but a train, a plane, a training, a Tour de France, whatever.

To further quote user @jlliagre:

> C'est peut-être une influence de l'anglais où retard et retarded sont des insultes. En France, on dira plutôt attardé quand il s'agit de retard mental : Pierre est un attardé, il n'arrive pas... Le sens largement le plus courant de retardé correspond à l'anglais delayed.

See

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+retard%2Cest+en+retard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cest%20retard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cest%20en%20retard%3B%2Cc0

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_retard%C3%A9/68821

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/retard#fr

and the comments following my answer.

Comment: Why does it not exist?

Comment: Where else can I use en like that?

Comment: @robertpatrick. I am not a native as I said. I think être en retard (that is, with the preposition *en*) is a set expression.

Comment: @robertpatrick It is a set expression which can be conveyed in English by 'be late'. French only sometimes is conveyed word-by-word by a English structure. Conversely, English only sometimes is conveyed word-by-word by a French structure.

Comment: @robertpatrick (il) est retard simply does not exist: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+retard%2Cest+en+retard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cest%20retard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cest%20en%20retard%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @robertpatrick See the edit.

Comment: I get it that way but what is the reason I am not able to understand

Comment: Thank you for being with me

Comment: @robertpatrick. May be I sound dogmatic but until a native verifies (or not:-)!) my assertion the only reason I see is that the expression is set that way (that is, with **en**).

Comment: @robertpatrick I think être and retard (a noun) does not make sense. It is by en that the whole set expression conveys be late (late is an adjective here).

Comment: *Être + noun* only works for identity things, such as professions. "Il est médecin." Since *retard* means "delay", the construction would be ungrammatical. Even if *être retard* did work, it would apparently mean "He is a delay."

Comment: @robertpatrick I confirm, from a native speaker, that 'il est retard' is an error, it miss something, like Dimitris wrote it miss en, or it miss the 'é'. A note, to tell 'retardé' is an insult, it's pejorative.

Comment: @yagmoth555 That's not necessarily an insult. For example you can say *Pierre est retardé ! Pourquoi ? À cause de la tempête de neige* : "Pierre is delayed! Why? Because of the snow storm."

Comment: @Dimitris You should add this meaning of *être retardé* in your reply. It makes more sense to compare it with *être en retard*, and there is a difference between *être retardé* and *être en retard*, in the former case, you are still travelling and you might even be able to catch up while in the latter case, it's too late for you to be on time.

Comment: @jlliagre Une insulte quand ont parle de la déficiance comme l'explication de Dimitris. Change ton exemple à; "Pierre est retardé, il n'arrive pas a enlever la neige et est en retard a cause de cela." Le sens n'est vraiment pas pareil, mais je suis d'accord que le sens peut etre correct, mais j'aime mieux prévenir que c'est péjoratif dans le contexte du larousse, l'explication du larousse ne le marque pas.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Ta dernière phrase ne marche pas en France. C'est peut-être une influence de l'anglais où *retard* et *retarded* sont des insultes. En France, on dira plutôt *attardé* quand il s'agit de retard mental : *Pierre est un attardé, il n'arrive pas...* Le sens largement le plus courant de **retardé** correspond à l'anglais *delayed*.

Comment: @jlliagre ah! c’est bon a savoir pour la difference. Si ont creuse le sujet a noter ici le mot peut dire comme le larousse. Donc un retard, mais attardé est plus qu’un retard. Nuance comme debil leger versus handicapé lourd. Cela a meme influencé ici des termes de diagnostique scholaire en example; retards du language versus un trouble du language. Le principle reste que retard reste possible a rattraper, versus un trouble ou handicap qui va rester pour la personne toute sa vie. Tout cela pour dire que retardé veut pas dire exactement attardé.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=action+retard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caction%20retard%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caction%20retard%3B%2Cc1 , "action retard" → oral (incorrect) : "*Ce médicament est* [à action] *retard*" : mais n'est pas utilisé  lorsqu'il s'agit d'une personne.